# Pandas Dataframe label selection

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

Can anybody tell me why df['2005-5-31'] trigger the KeyError exception?

```
rng = pd.date_range('2005', '2012', freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(len(rng), 3), rng, ['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
df.head()

# works
df.ix['2005-5-31']
df['2005-5-31':'2005-5-31']

# Gives KeyError: u'no item named 2005-5-31'
df['2005-5-31']
```

Follow code using df['2000-01-01'] works.

```
#multiple rows on a single date
rng = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2000-01-3', freq='8H')
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(len(rng), 3), rng, ['X', 'Y', 'Z'])

# works
df['2000-01-01']

                           X    Y   Z
2000-01-01 00:00:00 -0.227981    1.927932   -0.518947
2000-01-01 08:00:00  0.486063   -1.255186    0.375075
2000-01-01 16:00:00 -2.313950    0.654384    1.111493
```

Comment: please post your entire traceback error

Answer (score 1):

`df['2005-5-31']` is to select by column, but you don't have a column name `2005-5-31`.

`df['X']` works since you have a columns name `x`

### Edit

The reason `df['2005-5-31':'2005-5-31']` is to select by index but not column is because it doesn't make sense to make a slicing selection on columns.

For more information, take a look at [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html)

Comment: Thanks guys! I finally figure out the problem.  If there is only a single '2005-5-31' in the index column, then using df['2005-5-31'] generate the KeyError exception.  If in the index column has multiple 2005-5-31 rows, then using df['2005-5-31'] return those rows.

Answer (score 1):

`df['2005-5-31']` returns the column that is named: 2005-5-31. Your columns are named X,Y,Z. And because you don't have the date column, it is giving you an error!

Now the `.ix[]` method works because it takes up to two inputs, the first input being the row index. You have a row with the index `'2005-5-31'` so it works!